# Generate HTML output of page or record inside Scheduler Task even if it has restricted access

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

I am working on a scheduler task which sends emails to backend users to inform them that pages and/or records have to be updated/maintained. So after a record is created they receive mails after 30 days, that they should have look and edit the contents to keep everything up to date.
Now I want to attach pdf files with the html of the current page / record. All these pages / records have restricted access (OAuth). So if the scheduler task runs a curl request on the url, it gets only the contents of the login redirection.

Is there a way to generate a view via the scheduler task which returns html output even if the page has restrictions?

Comment: Assuming you have some credentials to get the secured object, then you need to add some more Curl to authenticate, like in this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53357741/how-to-perform-oauth-2-0-using-the-curl-cli. If you don't have credentials, then there is no way to get the object.